# Native linux bootable thumb drive with first partition as fat32

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, fat32

I've been trying to do this for quite a while and I feel like I have exhausted my options on it. I want to make a flash drive partitioned similarly to this:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         2930687   1.4 GiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
   2         2930688        31709183   13.7 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

First partition is fat32 (readable via windows) and second partition has a native installation of linux (don't care what distro/fs). The kicker is that I'm trying to boot this thumb drive on an HP server which apparently will not boot just any thumb drive. I think it has to be DOS-based. I've tried using grub to boot to the linux partition and it works great on different machines but on the HP machine it complains like this:

```
Attempting to Boot from USB DriveKey (C:)
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: out of disk
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Unfortunately, there are no thumbdrive/harddrive/boot options in the BIOS on this machine. Because it seems that grub is a "no-go" I thought I'd try to use syslinux but syslinux doesn't appear to support booting to different partitions. I have found that using syslinux and memdisk to boot an ISO on the fat32 partition works fine on the HP (like a LIVE iso) BUT I need to be able to customize some things in the linux installation - like mounting the fat32 partition and executing a script on boot-complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I feel your pain. I have had loads and *loads* of problems trying to do this with GRUB, and have had similar situations as yourself with various machines behaving differently, depending on how the storage is enumerated and passed to grub.

The problem you're probably having (if it's the same as what happened to me!) is that stage 2 is installed on the second, linux, partition along with the kernel in /boot and when stage 1 loads it can't find stage 2.

I managed to beat GRUB into submission eventually by buggering about in a chroot, and it was hateful, mainly because of disk device enumeration passed in from the BIOS (lots of manual grub.cfg editing). A far simpler solution is to use extlinux. Here's the process:

1. Partition flash drive with MBR, first partition ~1GB and second, the rest...
2. Ensure boot flag is set on first partition
3. Format partitions with FAT32 and something else (I use BTRFS)
4. Install extlinux on boot sector, `dd if=/usr/share/extlinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=440 count=1 conv=sync` (iirc debian uses `/usr/lib/syslinus/mbr/mbr.bin`)
5. Mount FAT32 partition (e.g. to /media/disk) and do `extlinux --install /media/disk`
6. Copy across extlinux libraries, `cp /usr/share/extlinux/{libcom32.c32,libutil.c32,menu.c32}
   /media/disk`
7. Copy across suitable kernel / initramfs into /media/disk
8. Extract your preferred linux rootfs into the other partition (or subvol if using BTRFS) and edit `/etc/fstab` to mount your FAT32 partition to /boot
9. Create `/media/disk/extlinux.conf`, mine looks like this [extlinux.conf](https://pastebin.com/EvzeNsYX)

Then try to boot - you should be away! Some notes from my struggles:

- BTRFS requires using PARTUUID in the bootloader, you can't seem to use the partition's base UUID; no idea why
- Because we're using MBR this isn't a process one can use with UEFI; a UEFI CSM is required
- I've never needed to use `altmbr.bin` but YMMV
- I used ext4 for the first partition, but it should work just fine with FAT32

Having the entire bootloader, plus kernel and initramfs on the first partition makes this a breeze, and I've yet to see it fail for any reason. I've built embedded x86 systems around this and it seems to be completely bulletproof.